ModuleNotFoundError: No module named aiosmtpd
I'm using Docker and I changed an Add-On to local, before I had a Docker-hub image. After changing that it's not working and now when trying to start the Add-On I'm getting an error as below.
Log

> [22:24:10] INFO: starting application...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/smtp2mqtt.py", line 13, in <module>
    from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiosmtpd'


Here is the DockerFile with before/after changes in it.
DockerFile original Github:

ARG BUILD_FROM

FROM $BUILD_FROM

WORKDIR /app

COPY start.sh smtp2mqtt.py /app/

RUN chmod 755 /app/start.sh

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip && pip3 install paho-mqtt aiosmtpd

ENTRYPOINT [“/app/start.sh”]

LABEL

io.hass.version=“VERSION”

io.hass.type=“addon”


DockerFile now:
ARG BUILD_FROM

FROM $BUILD_FROM

WORKDIR /app

COPY start.sh smtp2mqtt.py /app/

RUN chmod 755 /app/start.sh

RUN apk add --no-cache

RUN apk add python3

RUN apk add py3-pip

RUN apk add py3-paho-mqtt

CMD python3 -m aiosmtpd --nosetuid

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/start.sh"]

LABEL \

  io.hass.version="VERSION" \

  io.hass.type="addon" \

  io.hass.arch="armhf|armv7|aarch64|i386|amd64" 


I tried installing aiosmtpd separately with the pip install aiosmtpd command but it couldn't install.
